# quirky behavoir with rvest wikipedia scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, wikipedia, rvest

Sorry, this is a weird question, but I just can't seem to figure it out myself.  The good news is: I think it's totally reproducible.

I'm trying to build a simple R function to use {rvest} to scrape wikipedia for the hometown of musicians.  Basically, the function I wrote works, but for certain artists, it doesn't work (returns `NULL`).  (Randy Newman is one such, so I'll use him as an example.)

When I just run the whole thing (below) and then `findHome("randy newman")` I get `NULL` but then when I attempt to debug, I run the `tableMusic()` function and then `artist <- "randy newman"` and then run all the guts of the `artistData()` function line by line, IT WORKS!

AND THEN, once I've done that, I can run `findHome("randy newman")` and it will work right.  What gives?!  Do I have something in the wrong order or something?  I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
library(rvest)
findHome <- function(artist) {
##function to look for the table with the right info
tableMusic <- function(data) {
    if(!any(grepl("years active|labels|instruments", data[,1], ignore.case=T))) {
        for (i in 2:5) {
            data <- try(url %>% html %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[', i, ']', sep="")) %>% html_table(fill=T), silent=T)
            if(!class(data)=="try-error" & length(data)>0) {
                if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
                if(any(grepl("years active|labels|instruments", data[,1], ignore.case=T))) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(class(data)=="try-error" | length(data)<1) {
        data <- NULL
    } else if (!any(grepl("years active|labels|instruments", data[,1], ignore.case=T))) {
        data <- NULL
    }
    data
}
#function to pull data and try different pages if the first is wrong
artistData <- function(artist) {
    artist <- gsub(" ", "_", artist)
    artist <- gsub("'", "%27", artist)
    ##first try getting the data
    url <- paste("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", artist, sep="")
    data <- try(url %>% html %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]') %>% html_table(fill=T), silent=T)
    ##check if it's the right page (deal with disambiguation issues)
    if(!class(data)=="try-error" & length(data)>0) {
        if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
        data <- tableMusic(data)
    }
    ## if try-error or musicTable==NULL, try _(band)
    if(class(data)=="try-error" | is.null(data) | length(data)<1) {
        url <- paste("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", artist, "_(band)", sep="")
        data <- try(url %>% html %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]') %>% html_table(fill=T), silent=T)
        if(class(data)=="try-error"){
            data <- NULL
        } else {
            if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
            data <- tableMusic(data)
        }
    } else {
        if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
    }
    ## if try-error or musicTable==NULL, try _(musician)
    if(class(data)=="try-error" | is.null(data) | length(data)<1) {
        url <- paste("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", artist, "_(musician)", sep="")
        data <- try(url %>% html %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]') %>% html_table(fill=T), silent=T)
        if(class(data)=="try-error"){
            data <- NULL
        } else {
            if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
            data <- tableMusic(data)
        }
    } else {
        if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
    }
    data
}
## first try finding data
data <- artistData(artist)
## try finding with and/&
if(is.null(data)){data <- artistData(unlist(strsplit(artist, " and| &"))[1])}
## if no matches return ""
if(class(data)=="try-error" | is.null(data)) {
    data <- ""
    return()
} else {
    if(class(data)!="data.frame") {data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=F)}
}

## if we have a matching page, pull the relevant data
origin <- data[data[,1]=="Origin",2]
if(length(origin)>0) {
    home <- origin
} else {
    born <- data[data[,1]=="Born",2]
    if (length(born)>0) {
        home <- unlist(strsplit(born, "age.[0-9]+)"))[2]
    } else {
        home <- ""
    }
}
home
}

findHome("randy newman")
```

Comment: Something to do with nicknames? Or missing underscores?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to add a `url` parameter into the `tableMusic()` function.  As it was, it recycling the url from past searches.  Thanks for the suggestion.